# Django not redirecting to the right page

Tags: python, django, pycharm

What I get:
(Redirecting from login page)

```
Using the URLconf defined in webapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='blog-home']
about/ [name='blog-about']
register/ [name='register']
login/ [name='login']
logout/ [name='logout']
The current path, login/{ url 'register' }, didn't match any of these.
```

I want to redirect to the register/ page, but instead django goes to login/register.

**my main project urls:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),


]
```

(Pycharm can not find the users module in this file, however django doesn't report any error and is completely fine with it)

**my main project installed apps:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

**What I added to main project settings.py:**

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

**users views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an issue with your `login.html` template. You probably have a link in it like this:

```html
<a href="{ url 'register' }">Register</a>`
```

Unless you're changing Django's default template operator, you should be using `{%` for the url template tag:

```html
<a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>`
```

It's probably a good idea to read Django's page on templates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/

Here's the `url` tag specific docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url